# Windows Mobile - Get Encryption Key

Tags: security, encryption, windows-mobile, aes

Windows Mobile Supports Encryption (Settings -> System -> Encryption). My application needs to read encrypted files and decrypt it. How can I get encryption key used by Windows Mobile and decrypt it?

Comment: If you could just "get" the key, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of encryption?  You should only be able to decrypt data that you encrypted with your own, known key.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You are right. But, we have a requirement that we need to decrypt the data encrypted by native encryption. I know that it will defeat the purpose. But, I need to make sure that it is not possible. Thanks.

Comment: I gone throught one of the article of Windows Mobile Encryption FAQ (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsmobile/archive/2007/03/26/windows-mobile-6-storage-card-encryption-faq.aspx). In the answer of question, "Where are the encryption keys stored?", he repied that, "untrusted" application cannot access it. What does it mean? How can we install application as a trusted application? Can we retrieve Encryption key as a trusted application?

Comment: You'll have your app signed by a trusted third party: More details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms839681.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you want the key is to use it to decrypt an object, then just use the [CryptDecrypt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925738.aspx) function of the Windows Mobile [Cryptography API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920071.aspx).

-PaulH

Comment: But, which key I should use to decrypt?

Comment: You can enumerate the certificates in the store with `CertEnumCertificatesInStore` to get a `CERT_CONTEXT` structure then use `CryptImportKey` to get a key from that structure.

Comment: Are you sure that I can get the Encryption Key used by Native Encryption in Windows Mobile?

Comment: No, but if this is important to you it may be worth 20 minutes of your time to hammer out some test code to try this.